# Meteor up for mobile app

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I want to use meteor up to deploy my app to the server.
But when I deploy it, I can't find the apk file (usually when you build the app locally, it is located in the same folder as the bundle)

Is there a way to automatically generate the apk file with meteor up? or should I build it locally and point it to the deployment server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor up wont build your apk by default. You will have to do this yourself.